# How do I pass a customer keyup handler with params?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So say I have this ..

```
  keyup_handler: function(e, item){
    if (e.which == 27) {
      close_lightbox(item);
      return false;       
    };
  }

$(document).live('keyup', function(e){ keyup_handler(e, item) });
```

This is not returning any console.log()'s I place in here. So I assume that that it's not being touched. What am I missing? How do I pass the `e` or `event` to keyup_handler?

jQuery 1.4.4

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? I'd expect at 4.7k rep you'd have learnt how to ask a better question by now.

Comment: My apologies Anthony. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `false` from the call to `keyup_handler`, but not from the function that calls it, try doing:

```
$(document).live('keyup', function(e){ return keyup_handler(e, item); });
```

You may also need to modify `keyup_handler` slightly to `return true;` if the `if` statement doesn't evaluate to true.

I'm assuming here that your very vague "doesn't work" statement means that the usual keyup functionality isn't prevented when you release the corresponding key.

Also, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is a deprecated jQuery function, and isn't really intended for what you're using it for. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) or [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) otherwise.

Comment: Ah thanks! This worked. I had to throw in the return. My other handlers didn't need that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
$(document).live('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which == 27) {
close_lightbox(<selector-that selects-item>);
      return false;       
    }; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keyup_handler = function(e, item){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 27) {
      close_lightbox(item);
      return false;       
    }
}

$(document).on('keyup', 'dynamic_element', function(e){ keyup_handler(e, item) });​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VswCz/)

live() is deprecated, and not sure why you would need to use it on the document ?
For older versions of jQuery, I would think this would suffice:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){ keyup_handler(e, item) });​​​​​​​​​
```

Unless you have somehow managed to make the document level into a dynamic element ?